# How to draw multiple lines on the same graph in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, plot

I am new to tkinter and I need to be able to draw more than one line plot on the same chart each with its own legend.  I can do this in matplotlib using show () but then the graph becomes separate from the GUI window. My code takes files from a file list I have created and then plots them on the screen but keeps overwriting each graph - Is there a way of doing this so all the line charts appear on the same chart in tkinter?

```
    for item in myfile_list:
        x, y = np.loadtxt(item + '_' + 'Test.csv', skiprows=1, usecols=[x_axis_column, y_axis_column],
                          unpack=True, delimiter=',')
        # graph size in inches
        fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5))

        a = fig.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot(x, y, color='blue')
        a.set_title("Title", fontsize=16)
        a.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=14)
        a.set_xlabel("X", fontsize=14)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=chart_frame)
        # place graph in first row and column of chart_frame
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)
        canvas.draw()
        toolbar_frame = Frame(plot_frame)
        toolbar_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, toolbar_frame)
        toolbar.update()
```

Comment: You are creating a new `canvas` and `toolbar` in each iteration. Move these two outside of your loop.

Comment: I tried that and just get a blank canvas - will have another go

Comment: `canvas.draw()` or `canvas.draw_idle()` should stay inside the loop. Only the creation and geometry managing of the widgets should be outside.